# Add days to DateTime in PHP -- without modifying original

Tags: php, datetime

How can I add a number of days to a `DateTime` object without modifying the original. Every question on StackOverflow appears to be about `date` and not `DateTime`, and the ones that do mention `DateTime` talk about modifying the original.

Eg.

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-12-31');
$date->modify('+1 day');
```

But how can you calculate a date several days in advance without modifying the original, so you can write something like:

```
if($dateTimeNow > ($startDate + $daysOpen days) {
   //
}
```

I could always just create another `DateTime` object, but I'd rather do it the above way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use DateTimeImmutable, it's the same as DateTime except it never modifies itself but returns a new object instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php

Comment: Note, this is PHP 5.5 and above, so those needing 5.4 compatibility will need one of the other solutions (eg clone)

Answer (score 6):

you can take the original variable in a separate variable and add no. of days in other variable so you have both(original and updated)value in different variable.

```
    $startDate = new DateTime('2014-12-31');    
    $endDate = clone $startDate;
    $endDate->modify('+'.$days.'days');
    echo $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can always use `clone`, too:

```
$datetime = clone $datetime_original;
```

Comment: Hi Vicky, that is a valid option, but I do mention that in my question: "I could always just create another DateTime object, but I'd rather do it the above way."

Comment: hello chuck!! i just thought this might be usefull !!

Comment: `$datetime = clone $datetime_original;`

Comment: Spent a long time trying to figure this out without creating a new object, but there does not seem to be one.  I guess that makes sense, as a different date must be in a different object.  Ended up doing it in one line:  $endDate = (clone $startDate )->modify('+11 days');